# Long hold on back arrow of action bar in flutter shows a "Back" toast, how to remove that?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scaffold

How to remove the toast displayed on the Action bar in a flutter on Long hold on back arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `appBar` you can replace the `leading` parameter by what you want.

Try replacing it with :

```
AppBar(
   leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
         Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
   ),
),
```

It should remove the `tooltip`. If you want to customize it, see the `tooltip` parameter of `IconButton`

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IconButton` as leading widget of your `AppBar` like,

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      // tooltip: 'Back',  // this cause the overlay 
    ),
  ),
);
```